# Finding D1 and g for the following equation - infinite series question

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]

I've been trying to solve this economics question with infinite series, where we need to use the following two equations to find D1 and G, which is pretty straight-forward as there are two equations and 2 unknowns. I've tried isolating D1 from the first equation to input it into the second equation, getting me the following:

$(0.05-g)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1+g)^{n-1}}{(1.05)^n} = 26$

Now, I'm stuck. All I need is g to get D1, but I don't know what to do to get g, can someone tell me how I can do this?

Comment: write **(1+g)^{n-1}** and put a dollar sign before and after to render $(1+g)^{n-1}$

Comment: thanks, i'll put that in!